# PowerPoint in Latex

Tags: powerpoint

Is it possible to make a powerpoint presentation but using LaTeX?

Can you give some useful advices to start with?

The presentation is about chemistry.

Comment: As google helpfully points out, the beamer package was made exactly for these kinds of projects. Just use your normal tex editor.

Comment: See here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations

Comment: There's `powerdot` also, but I've never used it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If one wants to abandon pdflatex and use latex->dvips->ps2pdf, it's okay. But I did a chemistry presentation with `powerdot` and now know why I love Beamer.

Comment: @TeXnician: Well, I did not say it's good ;-)

Comment: I would never recommend using Texmaker (just a personal thing), but of course I would recommend the beamer package.

Comment: The question about the editor is a very personal one. I usually work with TeXworks or TeXstudio, but others like f.i. Emacs. You could have a look at our [big list of editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/124577).

Comment: The editor doesn't matter at all. Which one you use depends on which one you like most

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Johannes_B well pointed, the editor that  doesn't matter at all. BTW, I used Gummi for this example (yet another LaTeX editor, available in Debian)

What really matter in your case (I guess)  is:

```
$ firefox https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-spanish
$ texdoc beamer
$ texdoc chemfig 
$ texdoc everything ... 
$ firefox https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
$ firefox https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry
```

To start with all this mess you need a example of presentation, not a programme. Here you are one with some maths and chemistry to start to play:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % si no los quiero 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Mi linda \\ presentación}
\author{Santiago Miranda}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Matemáticas}

\begin{frame}{Una fórrmulas ...}{ ...sin sentido alguno}
Considerando que: 
\vfill
\[\sum^j_i = \sqrt{\frac{(x-y)^\epsilon}{\log(\rho)}}  \]
\vfill
Y que \ldots

\[ P\left(A=2\middle|\frac{A^2}{B}>4\right) \]
\vfill
Está claro que no tengo ni idea de lo que he escrito.
\end{frame}

\section{Química}

\begin{frame}{Me sube la adrenalina}{(cuando uso Beamer)}
\centering
\chemfig{*6((-HO)-=-(-(<[::60]OH)-[::-60]-[::-60,,,2]
HN-[::+60]CH_3)=-(-HO)=)}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Pero usando otras presentaciones}
{me sube el\ldots}
\centering
\setatomsep{2em}
\chemfig{[:30]R-(=[::+60]O)-[::-60]O-*6(--*6(=--*6(-*5(---(-(-[::+60]Me)
-[::-60]-[::-60]-[::+60]-[::-60](-[::-60]Me)-[::+60]Me)-)-(-[::+0]Me)---)--)-(-[::+0]Me)---)}
\vfill
\visible<2>{\alert{\huge COLESTEROL}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```